# Is there a way to use multiple Filter parameters from different Entity in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm Creating an Event Management asp.net core app, My Customer Entity is related with different Entities by many to many relations. know I want to filter my Customers depending on both Event Name and Main Category name Entities.

Here are my Entities

Customer

```
    public class Customer
    {
         public int Id {get; set;}enter code here
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public IList<CustomerEvent> CustomerEvents { get; set; }
         public IList<CustomerMainCategory> CustomerMainCategories { get; set; }
    
    }
```

Event

```
public class Event
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public IList<CustomerEvent> CustomerEvents { get; set; }
   }
```

CustomerEvent

```
public Class CustomerEvent
{
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

MainCategory

```
public class MainCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MainCategoryName { get; set; }
        public IList<CustomerMainCategory> CustomerMainCategories { get; set; }
        
    }
```

CustomerMainCategory

```
    public class CustomerMainCategory
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
        public MainCategory MainCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to Filter Customers that have same main category in the specified event.

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: Is thatwhat you want?
Go from a specific Event to the customers and display all that have overlapping CustomerMainCategory?

Comment: I want to get Customers that have both common Event and Common Main Category. just like this Get/Customers?Event="Event Name"&MainCategory"MainCategoryName"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
(untestet)

```cs
db.Customers.Where(
    c => c.CustomerEvents.Any(ce => ce.Event.Id == x)
    && c.CustomerMainCategories.Any(mc => mc.MainCategory.Id == y)
).ToList();
```